# past perfect continuous vs past perfect (perfect continuous vs perfect simple)

Tags: past-perfect, perfect-constructions, perfect-aspect, past-perfect-continuous

I read that the perfect continuous is an action that continuous up to another point and my teacher told me that usually these actions are ongoing or they end very close to the other point.

My question is that why should we use perfect continuous tenses for an action that ended very close to another point? Why can't we just use perfect simple? Is it the usage of perfect simple to end before the other point? For example:

> By the time l performed the song, l had been practicing for months.

Isn't it better to use it in past perfect simple because l finished my practice before l performed the song?

> By the time l performed the song, l had practiced for months.

Comment: No, it isn't 'better'. A native speaker would use the continuous tense to emphasise the ongoing nature of what went before. _By the time the bus arrived I had been waiting in the rain for an hour._

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/104866/kate-bunting what do you mean by ongoing nature? We can empathize the ongoing of the action until another point with perfect simple too. and that's why l don't understand which one should l use in this kind of situation.

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/104866/kate-bunting For example Cambridge dictionary says : We use the past perfect simple with action verbs to emphasise the completion of an event. We use the past perfect continuous to show that an event or action in the past was still continuing. 
 https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/past-perfect-simple-or-past-perfect-continuous

Comment: Please use my name with '@' in front instead of of linking to my profile! The continuous tense indicates that the action had been going on until the time being referred to, or would continue after it. The past perfect simple indicates that the action had been completed _before_ the time referred to. _I had waited for the bus for an hour, then given up and phoned for a taxi._